# Trying to repeat this program if user says Y

Tags: java

I have tried the other questions like this but none seem to match it. I want it to repeat if the user enters Y after the numbers are sorted in the console.
Here is the code:

```
package compsorter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ascending_Order 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int n, temp;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
    n = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) 
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("In Ascending Order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
    }
    System.out.print(a[n - 1]);
    s.close();
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a do while to do that!

Comment: You should learn about while and do... while loops.

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
do{
   //code here
   //take input from user 'Y' or 'N'
  }while(condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put 
`do {` after
`Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);`

and

`} while(s.readLine().equals("Y"))`
before
`s.close();`

Answer (score 0):

try do while for this reason.here is example of that : [link](http://www.java-examples.com/do-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with while loop. 
Below is main method program you should have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String flag = "Y";
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (true) {

  if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(flag)) {
    int n, temp;

    System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
    n = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[i] > a[j]) {
          temp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.print("In Ascending Order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
    }
    System.out.print(a[n - 1]);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Do you want to continue Y/N?");
    flag = s.next();

  } else {
    break;
  }
}
s.close();
}
```